# Which convex polyhedra can pass through a hole in themselves?

Tags: geometry, 3d

[Prince Rupert's cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Rupert%27s_cube)
is famous for passing through a hole in itself:

---

[image]

          

<sup>[Mark Frauednfelder video](https://boingboing.net/2017/04/03/video-of-cube-passing-through.html)</sup>

---

Wikipedia says 
"the same is true for the regular tetrahedron and octahedron."

My question is:

> ***Q***.
>   Have necessary (or necessary and sufficient) conditions been
>   identified for when a convex polyhedron can pass through a hole in itself?